# Asynchronous requests to server posted in a loop - Android

Tags: android, android-service, android-async-http

I am a Java developer with no Android experience, and I am trying to quickly put an app together. It seems that what I would normally do in Java isn't helping.

At this stage, ease of implementation is more important than efficiency or style - I will sort the latter out when there is more time and I will have educated myself properly when it comes to Android.

People can use the app to ask for support, or offer it to those who need it. Asking for support posts a request with the details to the server, and that's done.

Now I would like the app to post an asynchronous request to the server, to be notified of outstanding support requests once a minute. I guess it's the same principle of WhatsApp checking if there is any new message on the server.

I tried doing that in a separate thread with an infinite loop which sleeps for 60 seconds but for some reasons that stops the UI from working.

From what I now understand, I should use a service with a Looper, a Timer and a Handler. Is that correct?

Could anybody point me to a tutorial which explains exactly what to do, step by step? Or at least suggest keywords I should look for?

All I found so far are snippets of code which don't work together when I try to assemble it. Possibly because I am not searching for the right terms?

Thanks, Dan

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following approach:

- Create a service that runs in the background to check for newly added data in the server.
- If you prefer to make it user-driven, you can let users refresh the list on the device to actually trigger the requests to the server.
- Libraries like [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) can make your life easier when it comes to making http requests - always avoid the main UI thread when doing this.
- Another library that you could use to decouple your application using Events is [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). Assuming you are running a background service to check for updates, you can use EventBus to update your User Interfaces when something new is retrieved from the server through a GET request.

I hope this gives you an idea on how to proceed with the solution. Good luck!